# how to assign unique keys to a widget which is being used multiple times (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, key

```
Widget OptionField(String a, String b, Key key, int s) {
return AnimatedContainer(
    key: key,
    duration: Duration(seconds: 1),
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.07,
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(28),
        color: (s == 1)
            ? Colors.green
            : (s == 2)
                ? Colors.red
                : Colors.white),
    child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 0, 8, 0),
      child: Row(children: [
        Container(
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.055,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.055,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(25),
              color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 123, 0)),
          child: Text(
            '$a',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 24,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          width: 15,
        ),
        Text(
          '$b',
          style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 16,
              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ]),
    ));
```

THIS IS THE WIDGET WHICH IS BEING CALLED IN THE LISTVIEW MULTIPLE TIMES

```
Expanded(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.separated(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemCount: 4,
                      separatorBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return SizedBox(
                          height: 7,
                        );
                      },
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                        return InkWell(
                          onTap: () {
                            if (widget.QandAnsList[questionCounter]
                                    .Answers[index] ==
                                widget.QandAnsList[questionCounter]
                                    .CorrectAnswer) {
                              setState(() {
                                isCorrect = 1;
                              });

                              ca++;
                            } else {
                              setState(() {
                                isCorrect = 2;
                              });
                            }

                            if (questionCounter == questionMaxLength - 1) {
                              openDialog('Quiz Completed!',
                                  'Click on the Submit button below to see the Result');
                            } else {
                              Timer(
                                  const Duration(seconds: 2),
                                  () => setState(() {
                                        questionCounter++;
                                        isCorrect = 0;
                                        // optionColor = Colors.white;
                                      }));
                            }
                          },
                          child: OptionField(
                              option[index],
                              widget.QandAnsList[questionCounter]
                                  .Answers[index],
                              UniqueKey(),
                              isCorrect),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
```

This is the `ListView` code in which I'm assigning unique keys to the widget. Basically what I want is to change the `color` of the specific widget based on right or wrong answer but what happens is that it changes the `color` of all widgets despite assigning them unique keys.

Comment: the Key is not the issue you are passing the same isCorrect to all the widgets and it applies as it must be.

Comment: was facing the same issue before adding the 'isCorrect' parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setState() method rebuilds the state or in other words, it calls Widget build(ctx) method, so your listview is builded everytime. Instead try assigning each question a state and then change particular question's state to show true/false for that particular question

Answer (score 0):

try removing the global `isCorrect` variable and then define one inside the itembuilder.

```
itemBuilder: (context, index) {
    int isCorrect = 2;
```

**and the rest code will be the same.**